# listening event after using jquery append with flix media

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using flix media but it has problem when I change content use jQuery "append"

Normally, I use code, it shows normally: https://prnt.sc/p256e3

```
<div id="flix-inpage"></div>
<script src="https://media.flixfacts.com/js/loader.js" async="" type="text/javascript" xml="space" data-flix-distributor="15416" data-flix-language="en" data-flix-brand="lg" data-flix-mpn="OLED77C8LLA" data-flix-ean="8806098204656 " data-flix-sku="" data-flix-inpage="flix-inpage" data-flix-button-image="" data-flix-price="" data-flix-fallback-language=""></script>
<script src="https://media.flixfacts.com/js/loader.js" async="" type="text/javascript" xml="space" data-flix-distributor="15416" data-flix-language="en" data-flix-brand="lg" data-flix-mpn="OLED55C8PLA" data-flix-ean="8806098144242 " data-flix-sku="" data-flix-inpage="flix-inpage" data-flix-button-image="" data-flix-price="" data-flix-fallback-language=""></script>
```

It will show media. However, when I using jQuery append. (event not listen from external js file)

https://prnt.sc/p2568o
It same not get any event listen so the media can't show. Because js file of flix media from external site. So, I dont know how to process it.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: IT's really hard to help you if you don't provide us with an example of the problem or some more code.

Comment: I have updated it , can you pls check?